# Most Accurate jQuery Transition Time Translation Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

So; I've heard that a fair translation for jQuery transition delay time could be 1000 = 1 Second.

**Is this the most accurate / approximate way to translate?**

*EG*: Looking at the script below; I am trying to translate the delays / animations to the most approximate in seconds / milliseconds.

```
onReady=function(){
    $('#chart1_lines').delay(1000).animate({ width:97 }, 1000, 'easeOutQuad', onComplete1 );
}

onComplete1=function () {
    $('#chart1_values').css('width',156);
    $('#chart1_lines').delay(250).animate({ width:183 }, 1000, 'easeOutQuad', onComplete2 );
};
```

Comment: What do you mean?  What needs to be more accurate?  You need a queue of animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values - `1000`, `250`, etc - are times/durations in milliseconds, so every 1000 is precisely equal to 1 second.